# website legal notice font lightness requirement

Tags: css, html

foo5 is almost invisible. if any judgment occurs, I guess the Terms and Privacy would be valueless.

Is their any benchmark or specific indication for website legal notice font lightness (or even hue and saturation)?

Because I would like to make it light grey, in accordance with my web design.

```css
div{ font-size: 12px; }
#foo1{ color: hsl(0, 0%, 50%); }
#foo2{ color: hsl(0, 0%, 60%); }
#foo3{ color: hsl(0, 0%, 70%); }
#foo4{ color: hsl(0, 0%, 80%); }
#foo5{ color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%); }
```

```html
<div id="foo1">Copyright © 2018 exemple.com All rights reserved.| Terms of Service | Privacy Policy</div>
<div id="foo2">Copyright © 2018 exemple.com All rights reserved.| Terms of Service | Privacy Policy</div>
<div id="foo3">Copyright © 2018 exemple.com All rights reserved.| Terms of Service | Privacy Policy</div>
<div id="foo4">Copyright © 2018 exemple.com All rights reserved.| Terms of Service | Privacy Policy</div>
<div id="foo5">Copyright © 2018 exemple.com All rights reserved.| Terms of Service | Privacy Policy</div>
```

Comment: instant dislike ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: i read this 3 time and ... i didn't understand what you want ? and what is the issue ?

Comment: Would you give a short explanation why this question is bad and dislike after? Because I don't understand for now. Is my english bad?

Comment: i never said it's bad :) am commenting to understand what is about ... you got 4 downvotes and i can at max give one ;)

Comment: In footer of websites, there is legal notice right? it must not be, for exemple, transparent. I ask if its legal to style those footer with css and at which point.

Comment: well this a stuff of lawyers and not programmers .. here we help about programming issue not legal issue

Comment: I guess we can say the color doesn‘t matter as long as the human eye can read the linktext without problems.

Comment: Because if I style "Terms of Service | Privacy Policy" link with a relative pale color, in a judgment, the complainant could argue that the link was not clear enough and the judge could I imagine, cancel their value. Its pure guess. So I ask if there is criteria for this

Comment: This page might help you: https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/

Comment: @Temani Afif I know, but I was thinking that developers had to deal with it frequently, and it cover hsl notion. I'm sorry if its off topic then.

Comment: @Luckyfella could be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even Though this is no answer like providing code you can copy and paste it might help you to find the information you need related to you specific situation.

The W3C provides a guide about accessibility - here you find more information about their recommendations about contrast for texts:
https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#meaning

See paragraph 1.4 and later.

Here you find more detailed guidelines regarding the contrast:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#qr-visual-audio-contrast-contrast

To check the contrast of your text you could use this tool:
https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/

Summary: to judge if the contrast of your text is sufficient you need to read the resources and validate the contrast with the help of the suggested tool. There might be other tools around doing the same thing of course - so I don't claim it's kind of a official one.

I can't say if this is bulletproof in context of laws but I guess it could be a worthy argument relying on the W3C recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 is considered an industry standard at least in the US and in EU. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Content_Accessibility_Guidelines#Legal_obligations

This tool let you see if you meet the contrast standard of the WCAG.
https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker

Thanks to @Luckyfella for this link in the question comments.